# JS Push Array Not Working

Tags: javascript

Any idea why this will not push the TFW to the list. TFW is input from a text box that does work, but it will just not push it to the list.

I could not put the code in becuase StackOverflow was mad about how much code it was.

```
function tfw() {
    var goodTrump = [
        "america",
        "americans",
        "white people",
        "african americans",
        "black people",
        "blacks",
        "whites",
        "latinos",
        "latinas",
        "mexicans",
        "church",
        "christianity",
        "god",
        "jesus",
        "church and state",
        "trump",
        "money"
    ];
    var badTrump = [
        "mexico",
        "immigration",
        "muslims",
        "islamic terrorist",
        "terrorist",
        "islam",
        "democrats",
        "dexter"
    ];
    var sadTrump = [
        "death",
        "no money",
        "abortion",
        "public school system",
        "public schools"
    ];
    var done = [

    ];
    var TFW = document.getElementById("TFW").value
    for (i = 0; i < done.length; i++) {
        console.log(done[i]);
    }
    if (TFW == "") {
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='http://inthesetimes.com/images/articles/trump_flicker_face_yess.jpg'><br> Cant react to something not there.";
    } else if (badTrump.indexOf(TFW) !== -1) {
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='http://inthesetimes.com/images/articles/trump_flicker_face_yess.jpg'>";
    } else if (goodTrump.indexOf(TFW) !== -1) {
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='http://noiimages.s3.amazonaws.com/images/redstate/20160614-1525871659.jpg'>";
    } else if (sadTrump.indexOf(TFW) !== -1) {
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.mintpressnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/1033209603.jpg'>";
    } else {
        var failsafe = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        if (failsafe === 0) {
            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='http://inthesetimes.com/images/articles/trump_flicker_face_yess.jpg'>";
            goodTrump.push(TFW);
        } else if (failsafe === 1) {
            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='http://noiimages.s3.amazonaws.com/images/redstate/20160614-1525871659.jpg'>";
            badTrump.push(TFW);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.mintpressnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/1033209603.jpg'>";
            sadTrump.push(TFW);
        }
    }
}
```

Any one know what the problem is?

Comment: `I could not put the code in becuase StackOverflow was mad about how much code it was.` - well, post the **relevant** code

Comment: If it's that much code then it sure isn't a [mcve]. Note the word *"Minimal"*

Comment: That source cannot be found.

Comment: it's 67 lines of code ... perhaps you should describe more of the problem, that way the code:text ratio will be more acceptable ... don't just repeat yourself though, that's cheating

Comment: I've added the code for you - the proper indentation comes at no cost to you :p

Comment: not sure why you're attempting to console.log the contents of an array that is declared empty and never altered

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks and for debuging purposes i was trying to get it to push text into the array,

Answer (score 0):

You defined TFW with this code, but .value is not a function. If you log your value for TFW, it's probably undefined right now, which would be why you aren't able to push it to an array

You may be thinking of the jQuery function .val() which would return the content of the div with id TFW

```
var TFW = $("#TFW").val();
```

Alternatively, there is a pure javascript solution. If #TFW has no nested elements, you could use .innerHTML

```
var TFW = document.getElementById("TFW").innerHTML
```

Comment: TFW works, the program works what doesnt work is pushing things that have been inputing into the array